# function causes enq- DX contention

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

i have a crystal report that calls a function in Oracle. this function uses a select that selects a view as one of its' tables. this view uses multiple links to other databases(the view is a union of several queries). whenever this function runs, it appears as though the query for the view is run, and every link that creates the view seems to go into enq- DX contention.

is this related to this known issue?
http://surachartopun.com/2008/12/dbink-hangs-enq-dx-contention.html

the reason i ask is that my research seems to indicate that this problem should only happen when linking to different versiions of Oracle but all of the ones i am using are 10.2

Comment: what are the actual symptoms?  Does the report hang or throw error messages?

Comment: crystal hangs.... then if i go into oracle grid can see the link process is in  enq- DX contention . the function is a            pragma autonomous_transaction;

Comment: Your description is somehow only telling part of what is going on: in the description you talk about remote selects, but in the comments you talk about autonomous transactions? Can you give a complete description?

Comment: Steve - i assume i am only telling part of what is going on ... I am asking if anyone knows what else is hapening. as i stated, the Crystal report calls an autonomous transaction - that transaction runs a select that includes data from a view. the selects that create this view access data over links to other databases.

Comment: steve - I an happy to provide more info but i really need a more pointed question in order to be able to do so

Answer (score 0):

Has this method ever worked? It does not sound like a good way to do things. I can just imagine the function causing an enormous amount of round trips as it processes each row.

Some other ways of doing this include putting the function as close to the biggest data table as possible and keeping the processing on that database.  Only return what you need from the function.

You could create a table representing your desired data set from a query every morning and use Crystal to query that directly.  Just refresh your data as required using stored procedures or advanced queues.

A materialized view on one of the database sources with a refresh would be another approach.

EDIT:  yes, using database links can be resource intensive and cause the kind of problems you have seen.  Has this ever worked or is there a new requirement you need a solution to.
If it used to work what changed?
If this is new I humbly suggest a different approach as I have suggested.

Comment: I can run the individual pieces of the function as sql statments without issue (the problem only comes when running it as a function) and I can run the function when i don't include the view as part of the select within the function (i loose part of my criteria doing it this way).  I think the materialized view would work. Just seems strange that the pieces work but not the whole. I can also run the function ok as is if i run it against a view without links (this is in dev set up not production). The function runs very quickly as long as links aren't involved and hangs instantly when they are